# KOMA-Script and subcaption: wrong counting

Tags: numbering, koma-script, subcaption

I'm getting a to-me strange behavior when using `scrartcl` and `subcaption`.  In particular, numbering is doubled for each table with the default option `captions=tableheading`.  Here's an image (code at the end) with `captions=tablesignature`, notice how the counter only increase by one if the caption is below the table (I'm not suggesting any causality here):
[image: KOMA-Script, subcation and captions=tablesignature]

Here's the output when I switch to `captions=tableheading`:
[image: KOMA-Script, subcation and captions=tableheading]

I looked through the manuals of `KOMA-Script`, `caption` and `subcaption` but I didn't find anything that would suggest this behavior.  Is it a feature?  It's appreciate any hint on why this occur.

Here's the source

```
% bug(?), default setting for captions
\documentclass[captions=tablesignature]{scrartcl} %% same with scrreprt
% \documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrartcl} % no bug
\usepackage{subcaption}
\setkomafont{caption}{\LARGE}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{table one\label{tab:ind}}
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{expenses}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gnus & 3000\\
\hline
\textsc{(i)} & gnash & 146000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{income}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gnog & 100000\\
\hline
\textsc{(ii)} & gnus & 100000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
%% \caption{table two\label{tab:ind2}}
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{expenses}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gnus & 3000\\
\hline
\textsc{(i)} & gnash & 146000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{income}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gnog & 100000\\
\hline
\textsc{(ii)} & gnus & 100000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
%% could also use \captionbelow
\caption{table two\label{tab:ind2}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table three}
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{expenses}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gnog & 370000\\
\hline
\textsc{(iii)} & gug & 552000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{income\label{tab:ind3}}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline
& Konto & \textsc{dkk}\\
\hline
& gmag & 100000\\
& glog & 218000\\
\hline
\textsc{(iv)} & gnus & 318000\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error on either settings. which version are you using?

Comment: I use the latest version from TeX Live 2012.  For caption `cat-version: 3.3 (2013-02-03)` and for KOMA-Script `cat-version: 3.11b`.  Now that you point it out there is a newer version of caption on CTAN which I haven't tried since TeX Live 2012 froze and TeX Live 2013 isn't released.  IS that the version you're using?

Comment: I can reproduce the wrong counting with MiKTeX 2.9 (3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13), scrartcl.cls (2012/07/29 v3.11b), caption.sty (2013/04/14 v3.3-73) and subcaption.sty (2013/02/03 v1.1-62).

Comment: Perhaps you found a bug in one of the three packages. Would you mind to report it to http://www.komascript.de/ ? You can report in English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug, the behavior is IMHO correct. Since a `table` can contain more than one `\caption`, the `caption` package uses hints like `captions=tablesignature` to determine where it has to increase the table counter.

So when you use code like

```
\documentclass[captions=tablesignature]{scrartcl}
...
\begin{table}
% Table 1:
\caption{table one\label{tab:ind}}
% Table 2:
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{expenses}
...
\end{subtable}
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{income}
...
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

the `caption` package sees two tables here: The one titled "table one" which ends directly after the `\caption` (and has no content, but the `caption` package does not know this!), since `captions=tablesignature` is specified. Afterwards a second table (without caption) is following. The `table` counter will be incremented for the second table because of the sub-tables. (A `\ref` to the first sub-table will therefore lead to "2a".)

If you really want to have a top caption even if `captions=tablesignature` is set, you have to give the `caption` package a hint about that, for example by using `\captionabove` instead of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass[captions=tablesignature]{scrartcl}
...
\begin{table}
% Table 1:
\captionabove{table one\label{tab:ind}}
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{expenses}
...
\end{subtable}
\qquad
\begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\caption{income}
...
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

(A `\ref` to the first sub-table will lead to "1a" here, since the `caption` package knows that the content follows the `\caption` since `\captionabove` is used.)

But why the output is as intended when using the `article` class instead? This is not really true, if you use the `article` class and load the `caption` package with option `tableposition=b`, you will get the same behavior.
My fault, I will add a section about the relationship of the `position` option with the `figure` and `table` counter in the next version of the documentation.

And why is there "no bug" if `captions=tableheading` is used instead? Well, this seems to be a real bug to me since "Table 2: table two" should be "Table 3: table two" here, I need to examine this...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Note though, that `captions=tablesignature` is the default so I wasn't really trying to cheat it.  I was just trying to a subtable configuration a la `subfigure` (in general I prefer subcaption).  So would you advice a different approach to setting up a one-table-two-subtabulars kind of thing?

Comment: @Rasmus The stuff about "cheating" should be fun, so no, of course you did not try to cheat. (My humor does not seem to be compatible, so I just removed that in my answer.) It's not clear to me what the remaining problem is. Setting `captions=tableheading` and putting `\caption` at the top of the `table` should not only help about the countering but also should fix the spacing between `\caption` and content (since KOMA-Script uses this setting for using the correct spacing here).